# Save all pdf files which are attached to mail to a specific directory

Tags: macos, applescript

I use apple mail, and I want to create a rule, which uses at the end a AppleScript.
This apple script should save all attached pfd files of this mail to a specific folder.

How can I realize this?
Is there somewhere a ready script?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why don't you try a search?

Answer (score 0):

Derived from a template in /Library/Application Support/Script Editor/Templates/Mail

```
using terms from application "Mail"
on perform mail action with messages these_messages for rule this_rule
    tell application "Mail"
        set the message_count to the count of these_messages
        repeat with i from 1 to the message_count
            set this_message to item i of these_messages
            
            -- EXAMPLE: save images attached to the message, to the pictures folder
            -- PROCESS IMAGE ATTACHMENTS
            tell this_message
                set these_attachments to every mail attachment
                set the pictures_folder_path to (path to pictures folder)
                repeat with z from 1 to the count of these_attachments
                    set this_attachment to item z of these_attachments
                    -- LOOK FOR IMAGE ATTACHMENTS
                    if the MIME type of this_attachment begins with "image" then
                        set this_name to the name of this_attachment
                        set target_file to ((pictures_folder_path as string) & this_name) as «class furl»
                        -- DOWNLOAD AND SAVE IMAGE FILE
                        try
                            with timeout of 180 seconds
                                save this_attachment in target_file
                            end timeout
                        on error
                            display dialog "Error saving " & this_name
                        end try
                    end if
                end repeat
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

The most obscure obstacle was the actual save operation.
It only works when you to qualify the file

```
... as «class furl»
```